# Implementing a .png and .ico favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

Am i able to put 2 favicon links in my `<head>` file?

Currently its like this in the header section :

`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="sitelink/favicon.png" />`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="sitelink/myicon.ico" />`

But Chrome still displays the .ico one first.

Am I doing anything wrong? I just want Chrome/Firefox/Safari to display the .png favicon, while if the browser is IE, I want it to display the .ico format.

How do i go about displaying it? My way of thinking was that if the .png link was at the top it would load first and if it didn't (IE) it would load the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. Looks like I just found the cross browser favicon implementation after poking around a bit more.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="sitelink/favicon.png">

<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="sitelink/favicon.ico"/><![endif]--><!-- Internet Explorer-->
```

This should go into the `<head>` section of HTML.